# Translation of Cabeo's Philosophia magnetica

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, magnetism

Is there a translation of [Niccolò Cabeo](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niccol%C3%B2_Cabeo)'s work *Philosophia magnetica* into English (or other modern language)? The original text in Latin is available for example [here](https://preserver.beic.it/delivery/DeliveryManagerServlet?dps_pid=IE7320178) but I can't find any translation (unlike William Gilbert's *De Magnete* for example).

Comment: There's no English translation of the full text that I'm aware of. I translated the section on his electrical experiments here: https://histomathsci.blogspot.com/2022/02/translation-of-excerpts-of-niccolo.html
It's incomplete (leaves out the section on theory) because my focus was on the experimental side. I have notes from the theoretical stuff laying around somewhere..